# Building IOS application with cordova

Tags: ios, cordova, build, apk

I have a web application that i built with html, css and javascript.

I was able to bring the project into the cordova frame work and it built successfully and i used the simulator and it opened properly but now I ran the "cordova build ios" command which built and showed me the file that it built but when i send it to an ios device(i used the iphone 11) it does not work, i cant even download the app on the device talk more of installing it

And also the after running the build commang it gives me a zip file (not sure why).

I saw some write ups online thats suggested something concerning the version of my xcode and if it was compatable with the devices OS version

i tried upgrading my OS version and these are the version and apps i am using

Mac OS Version: 12.7.1 (21G918)
Xcode Version: 14.2 (14C18)
Iphone 11 Version: 16.5.1

Comment: what do you mean by " it does not work"? does it open? is it a blank screen? does it crash? any errors sown in xcode console?